# Converting between unsigned long and uint8_t array

Tags: c, arduino, mifare, adafruit

I am trying to read and write an unsigned long type value to an NFC card.

I am working with the pn532 module, the MifareUltralight card, and the Adafruit library. The mifareultralight_WritePage function seems to accept only an array of type uint8_t which size of 4-byte.

So I want to store a four-byte long type value in a Uint8_t array by one by one and convert a Uint8_t array of 4-byte length into one long type variable.

```
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>

...

uint8_t writeBuffer[4] = { 18, 52, 86, 120 };
nfc.mifareultralight_WritePage(8, writeBuffer);
```

```
uint8_t readBuffer[4];
success = nfc.mifareultralight_ReadPage(i, &readBuffer[0]);
    if (success) {
        nfc.PrintHex(readBuffer, 4);
}
```

Comment: what is your problem ? the little/big endian order ?

Comment: The 80C51 is big endian, but you must check the documentation to know in which order the bytes are sent by the mifare module.

Comment: @bruno I am not familiar with C. So, I can not do type conversion between unsigned long and uint8_t []

Comment: @snark I put an answer

Comment: @AlainMerigot 8051 is a dinosaur 8-bitter so it doesn't have endianess. I believe it stores addresses according to little endian though. Intel being the #1 little endian crusaders.

Comment: If you use a compiler, it is not true. I have seen on [this site](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_xe.htm) that "All other 16-bit and 32-bit values are stored, contrary to other Intel processors, in big endian format, with the high-order byte stored first." So I assume it is the convention used by the compiler.

Comment: @AlainMerigot All that matters is the order that CPU wants two 8 bit registers to form a 16 bit index register for addressing. Addresses should be in that format.

Comment: Right. I did not look at your answer, but as you do the conversion with shift and add, it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

in

> ```
> uint8_t writeBuffer[4] = { 18, 52, 86, 120 };
> ```

if the index 0 contains the lower byte just do for instance

```
uint8_t writeBuffer[4] = { 18, 52, 86, 120 };
unsigned long v = writeBuffer[0];

for (size_t i = 1; i != 4; ++i)
  v += ((unsigned long) writeBuffer[i]) << (i * 8);
```

if the index 0 contains the higher byte just do for instance

```
uint8_t writeBuffer[4] = { 18, 52, 86, 120 };
unsigned long v = writeBuffer[3];

for (size_t i = 1; i != 4; ++i)
  v += ((unsigned long) writeBuffer[3 - i]) << (i * 8);
```

Comment: It seems the question was not accurate because of my terrible English. Anyway, this usage of the shift operator shows me a way. thank you.

Comment: @snark no problem. If you want you can delete your question, or edit it to remove all concerning the hardware and be general but conform to its title (and in that case you can accept my answer). Good continuation